# Firebase Cloud Functions - Func Definition Performance

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm arranging my code in index.ts on simple line function definitions like:

Http Example

```
export const demoHttpApp = functions.https.onRequest(
  (req, resp) => new DemoHttpClass(req, resp).run()
);
```

Real Time Database Example

```
export const demoRtDb = functions.database.ref(DemoRtDbClass.PATH)
  .onWrite(event => new DemoRtDbClass(event).run());
```

The idea is to develop the class by class and test them outside.

Every class constructor returns **this**, to be able to call a clas member.

**I want to know** if this could produce some memory leak or any type of malfunction.

As the work is for complex operations, I really prefer to use the methods of the object and have them isolated from the rest of the calls.

But I don't want to create a issue, or pay for a long freeze instance because of a mistake.

I understand that when the function is finished, the reference to the object is lost, and the memory is freed. I like to know if I get it right.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The biggest issue I see is that you're creating a new instance of your object every time the function is invoked.  A better pattern is to initialize the object outside of the function.  When a new instance is spun-up it will create the new object and then every time the function is invoked it can use that same object over and over again which will use less memory in the long run.

```
var demoHttpApp = new DemoHttpClass();
export const demoHttpApp = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => 
    demoHttpApp.run(req, res);
);
```

Another benefit to this is you can pass in the Firebase database or auth admin objects through the constructor which will make those objects easier to test as well.

Here is an example of injecting the admin database object:

```
var databaseClass = new DemoRtDbClass(admin.database());
export const demoRtDb = functions.database.ref(DemoRtDbClass.PATH).onWrite(event => 
    databaseClass.run(event)
);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I'm sure it's useful for small functions. In my case I have complex work and not urge to performance. I'll edit the question.